Colors messed up for no reasons
I've used Ubuntu for a few month now without any issues. Today, as I boot, I can see that the orange logo on the login screen is blue. When I log-in, I can see that anything supposed to be blue (such as the thunderbird icon) as turned orange. Also, anything that was supposed to be orange (such as the Civ6 icon) as turned blue.
I've looked online for suggestions, I've upgraded apt, reinstalled ubuntu desktoped, removed and tried every single color profile, but nothing has brought back the normal color scheme.
I tought about a wire issue, but when I shut the computer off, once the profile is logged out the ubuntu icon is orange as it should be.
Here is a screenshot of my icons :
icon colors are all messed up (look at the thunderbird icon for instance)
Somehow, It seems that everything that has a white background works fine (for instance typing this post shows blue links) but anything with dark or non-white background is messed up (for instance the firefox tab bar)
typing a post (as you can see the link is blue)
tab icons on firefox (as you can see the facebook icon is orange)

Strange, all the screenshots you posted are normal colors, but I had this exact issue just a few days ago.
Changing picom from GLX to Xrender or Xpresent would partially solve the issue.
Are you using the Oibaf driver PPA by chance? It seems the most recent build has fixed the issue, though, so try updating and see if that resolves it.

Indeed, screenshots were fine, how odd. Yesterday, I still had the issue, but today... it's gone ! Now colors are back to normal ! If it comes back, I'll have a go at what you suggested, but so far I don't know which driver or picom i'm using.
I've seen also that there is a v24 that was released (I'm on ubuntu22 right now), if the issue comes back I'll upgrade. Thank you for your feedback.
